# Keycloak OpenID Connect - Github

Tags: github, keycloak, openid, openid-connect

I want to connect Keycloak to the identity provider of my organization but it is failing.
To test the connection between Keycloak and other identity providers I have used Github and connected it with Keycloak using the default template of Keycloak for Github and it worked.

Now I am trying to connect Github with Keycloak using the generic "OpenID Connect v1.0" configuration to check if it can help me somehow, but I didn't succeed. I was redirected to the Github login page, logged in but then, when redirected back to Keycloak, Keycloak is sending the error "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider".

Has anyone managed to connect Github to Keycloak using the generic "OpenID Connect v1.0" configuration?

In Keycloak I have used this configuration:

Authorization URL:
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize

Token URL:
https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token

In Github I have configured the application with:

Homepage URL:
https://MY_IP/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/broker/githubcustom/endpoint

Authorization callback URL:
https://MY_IP/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/broker/githubcustom/endpoint

Comment: Nothing usefull on debug logs?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub supports `OAuth` and not `OpenID Connect v1.0`. So I wouldn't expect that it will be working. I would use `Social->GitHub` provider type.